# How to refresh pivot table in VBA

Tags: vba

I tried to refresh pivot table in VBA with the following script

```
Sub Main
Application.Workbooks.Open("D:\IT_Routines\PivotTables\SalesAnalysis_AU_TLO.xlsx",,,,"ACASales",,,,,,,,,,)
 Rem Application.Visible = True
  Rem Windows("SalesAnalysis_AU_TLO.xlsx").Activate
  Rem Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SalesAnalysis").Select
  Rem  Application.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesAnalysis").PivotCache.Refresh
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll()
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
End Sub
```

When I run this in Automate 11 showing syntax error as [Main](Step 1) Syntax error, possibly missing required parameter in function call

Comment: ACASales is the password, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the workbook so you can directly refer to your object rather relying on `ActiveWorkbook`. This will also allow you to use a `With` block resulting in a slightly cleaner, and easier to follow, code.

```
Sub Main ()
Dim MyBook As Workbook
Set MyBook = Workbooks.Open("D:\IT_Routines\PivotTables\SalesAnalysis_AU_TLO.xlsx", Password:="ACASales")

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With MyBook
    .RefreshAll
    .Save
End With

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I also recommend turning off `Screen Updating` and `Alerts` once you have this working to help speed things up a bit. The code is here, just commented out for you to add back in on completion.

---

If you want to save & close the workbook change `.Save` to `.Close True`

Comment: When I run the code it's showing unable to get the open property of the workbooks class, error code -1004

Comment: Double check/triple check that you have the right path. Make sure you have access to the location where the book is stored (can test with a excel on desktop as well)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue. Problem was not with the VBA code, "enable background refresh" property was on in my excel file.To resolve the issue, "Go to the data tab, click connections in the connections group, click on EVERY connection and click properties, un-check the box that says "enable background refresh"".